# Expo - React Native Android - Post Message Doesnt Work After Building

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I am using [react-native-bluesnap-encrypter](https://github.com/uditalias/react-native-bluesnap-encrypter/blob/master/src/BlueSnapEncrypter.js) to encrypt credit card data. This code uses a WebView and a post message to send the encrypted data from the webview back to the app. Everything works fine in development, but when I build the standalone android app it stops working and the webview content is not available for debugging at this point.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In the component rendering this WebView the html was imported like this:

```
const html = require('./bridge.html');

// ...

// ...
<WebView source={html} />
```

`require('./bridge.html')` This will only work in development on android, not production. I fixed it by putting the `bridge.html` in an s3 bucket and add it to the web view like this:

```
<WebView source={{ uri: 'https://s3.../bridge.html' }} />
```